# filter wont filter undefined

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

been staring at this code for while now..

Need some help

I have this filter, and im trying to remove undefined objects from array:

```
  .then((items) => {
    const filtered = items.map( i => {
      if (i !== undefined) {
        return i
      }
    })
    updateState(filtered, query)
  });
```

Followed by the filtered giving error:

```
Argument of type '({ service: Service; results: Card[]; } | undefined)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SearchResult[]'.
  Type '{ service: Service; results: Card[]; } | undefined' is not assignable to type 'SearchResult'.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'SearchResult'.
```

when i try to pass it to updateState() function.

Shouldn't the filter do just that? remove the undefined items from the array..
What is going on here?

EDIT: Even filtering with type assertion gives the same error..

```
const filtered: SearchResult[] = results.filter( i => i as SearchResult)
```

With same result..

Thanks

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out Typescript is not able to figure the type of return here..

after long while abusing google searches with different keywords i came up with this line

```
const filtered: SearchResult[] = results.filter( (i): i is SearchResult => !!i)
```

I got it from this blog post:
https://www.benmvp.com/blog/filtering-undefined-elements-from-array-typescript/

Have a nice day everyone!

Answer (score 2):

When using `map` to filter out `undefined` (or other types) values, you can actually use `flatMap` instead (if you don't wnat to use `filter`).

Here is how:

```js
const filtered = items.flatMap((item) => (item ? [item] : []));
```

Note that this way, Typescript will infer the correct type for your array

or, with full syntax:

```js
const filtered = items.flatMap((item) => {
  if (item !== undefined) return [item];
  else return [];
});
```

You can even remove the unnecessary square brackets:

```js
const filtered = items.flatMap((item) => {
  if (item !== undefined) return item;
  else return [];
});

const filtered = items.flatMap((item) => (item ? item : []));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not return a value from the `map` function, it returns `undefined`, so the return from your current code for an `undefined` value is still `undefined`.

You can get your desired result by using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead of map, or by returning a default value other than `undefined` when your map encounters `undefined`.

Comment: Sorry to say this, but thats the problem, it does not

Comment: I don't understand your comment. The code you posted is using the `map` method, which is behaving exactly like it's supposed to. The behavior you seem to want is better achieved using `filter` instead.

Comment: Map, with return yes. and also edit has filter which also is not working.. but i found the answer! thanks for help anyways : )